# Good explicit naming style for hash in Ruby (and other languages)

Tags: ruby, hash, naming-conventions

I have a hash whose keys are country codes and values are arrays of language codes spoken in the corresponding country. For example:

```
h['BE']  
#=> ['fr', 'nl', 'de']
```

Would `languages_by_countries` be a good explicit name for my hash ? In particular is it correct to use the plural form to denote both the values (languages) and the keys (countries) ? Are there other more commonly used naming conventions in my case ? Does Ruby differ here from other languages like Java ?

Comment: How about countries_languages ? Borrowed from mapping table name.

Comment: This is a question that would be more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Belongs in code review - asking for naming suggestions

Answer (score 2):

There's no definite answer to your question and it usually depends on your coding style. 
However, it's a good practice to assign plural names for arrays and hashes that have multiple records. 
For example `user_ids = [1,2,3,4,5]` makes sense as it clearly means the array has multiple user ids.  Also it isn't wrong to name it `users_ids` as it also makes sense that the array has ids of multiple users.

In your example I could also name it `country_languages` which is absolutely fine as it serves the purpose and perfectly understandable to other developers.

As I said, it all depends on your coding style but following general naming conventions is always good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Let's agree with Pamio in that there is no definite answer to your question. However, if you have codes rather than countries and languages, I would say that the word 'code' should be part of the name. Now, if you encapsulate the access to your data, there should be no reason for emphasizing that the collection of language codes is grouped by country codes. To me this distinction only reflects implementation details that refer to how you retrieve codes. The key functionality of your collection (which happens to be a mapping) isn't in the organization of its elements, but in the ability it facilitates to respond to a variety of queries about language codes (certainly by country, but also by region, by continent, by hemisphere.) In sum, I would consider language_codes a valid alternative in your case.